# Laravel: check if model is child of a relation

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have three models: `A`, `B`, `C`

- `A` hasMany `B` via `getB()`
- `B` belongsTo `C` via `getC()`

Having the following code:

```
$A = A::first()->load('getB');

$A->getB->load('getC');
```

Is there a way in Laravel to check within model `C` if itself is a child of `B`, or within `B` if itself is a child of `A` ?

Comment: If I properly  understand, then your query will be `$q= Car::has('books')->get();` C = Car,  B = books. If C has relation with B,  then you will get the collection.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say:

- A book has many reviews.
- A review belongs to a user.

So to check whether a user owns/wrote a review:

```
class Review extends Model
{
    public function author()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}

$review->author->is($user);
// Or
$user->reviews->contains($review);
```

The same with book and reviews:

```php
$book->reviews->contains($review);
$review->book->is($book);
```

I hope that answer your question.